# Changing user input

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am writing some code for a game and following some online class instructions, which the video instructor told me to branch off and explore my on my own to make it more unique. How can I make my code on level select say "You have picked Zoo Database." instead of having it say "You have picked 1 Database."?

This is what I have currently for my level selection:

```
void Start(){
    ShowMainMenu();
}

void ShowMainMenu(){

    Terminal.ClearScreen();
    Terminal.WriteLine("What would you like to hack into?");
    Terminal.WriteLine("Press 1 for Zoo Database");
    Terminal.WriteLine("Press 2 for UN Database");
    Terminal.WriteLine("Press 3 for Microsoft Database");
    Terminal.WriteLine("Make your selection:");
}

int level;
void OnUserInput(string input)
{
    if (input == "menu"){
        ShowMainMenu();
    }
    else if (input == "1"){
        level = 1;
        StartGame();
    }
    else if (input == "2"){
        level = 2;
        StartGame();
    }
    else if (input == "3"){
        level = 3;
        StartGame();
    }
    else{
        Terminal.WriteLine("Please choose a vaild Database.");
    }
}

void StartGame()
{
    Terminal.WriteLine("You have chosen the" + level "database");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would set the text description the same way you set the level.

```
int level;
...
else if (input == "1"){
    level = 1;
    StartGame();
}
```

becomes

```
int level;
string levelDescription;
...
else if (input == "1"){
    level = 1;
    levelDescription = "the zoo level";
    StartGame();
}

Terminal.WriteLine("You have chosen the" + level "database");
```

would become

```
Terminal.WriteLine("You have chosen " + levelDescription + " database");
```

Answer (score 0):

From all i could deduce from your question, you want to replace the level with the associated database name from your input. You could create a dictionary and use the level as the key and the database name as the value and use the key to get the value each level.